# how i call this function in oracle database?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRODUCT(PRODUCT_CODE PLS_INTEGER ) 
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    PRODUCT NUMBER:=0;
    BEGIN
       SELECT  PRODUCT_CODE INTO PRODUCT FROM PGIM_PRODUCT
       WHERE PRODUCT_CODE=PROD_DESC ;
    RETURN PRODUCT;
END PRODUCT;
```

Comment: "Call" is a term for procedures. Your function must be used in the query by the same way as any common built-in function is used. `SELECT id, PRODUCT(id) AS code FROM ...`

Comment: PS. Do you really provide a description (you check PGIM_PRODUCT.PROD_DESC  column) as PRODUCT_CODE (parameter name)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call in a PL/SQL block

```
DECLARE
return_val NUMBER;
BEGIN
return_val := product(101);
END;
```

If you want to call it in a query

```
SELECT product(100) FROM dual;
```

Qualify the name if it is in a different schema from the schema you are calling.

EDIT:

"create a single query with the help of user define function......in user define function a single parameter is passed which is product_code and its return product_desc from the table PGIM_PRODUCT"

if you want this then your query is wrong

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRODUCT(PRODUCT_CODE_IN PLS_INTEGER ) 
RETURN varchar2
IS
    PRODUCT_DESC varchar2(32767);
    BEGIN

       SELECT  PRODUCT_DESC INTO PRODUCT_DESC FROM PGIM_PRODUCT
       WHERE PRODUCT_CODE =  PRODUCT_CODE_IN;

    RETURN PRODUCT_DESC;
END PRODUCT;
```

Comment: PGIM_PRODUCT is separate table i want product_DESC by using product_code parameter. product_DESC is a column name exist in PGIM_PRODUCT

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Comment: What you want to do with this -  SELECT  PRODUCT_CODE INTO PRODUCT FROM PGIM_PRODUCT
       WHERE PRODUCT_CODE=PROD_DESC ;

Comment: create a single query query with the help of user define function......in user define function a single parameter is passed which is product_code and its return product_desc from the table PGIM_PRODUCT

Comment: ERROR line 13, col 8, ending_line 13, ending_col 12, Found 'FETCH', Expecting: ;   -or-   FOR  ORDER   -or-   INTERSECT  MINUS  UNION   -or-   CONNECT  GROUP  HAVING  START   -or-   OR   -or-   AND   -or-   ||   -or-   /   -or-   **   -or-   (+)   -or-   %  .  [   -or-   :  @  CASE  CONNECT_BY_ROOT  decimal number  EXISTS  FALSE  float  integer  NEW  PRIOR  SQL  TRUE   -or-   (  *  +  -  AT  CONTINUE  CURSOR  DAY  identifier  MOD  MODEL  MULTISET  NOT  NULL  REM  string  THE  WHEN  YEAR

Comment: remove the fetch

Comment: AFTER REMOVING FETCH THIS ERREOR OCCURE.........PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PRODUCT_CODE": invalid identifier